# ASP page not displaying Stored Procedure OUTPUT

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado

I have an ASP page calling a stored procedure with returned values AND OUTPUT parameters.

The output parameters aren't displaying and I'm not understanding why:

```
<%
  dim Objrs, cmd
  set Objrs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open strConnect
  set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  cmd.CommandText="MKTG_Current"
  cmd.CommandType=adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@added", 135, 2)
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@named", 200, 2, 50)

  set Objrs = cmd.Execute
%>
    </div>
    <div id="recent-news-box" class="rounded-corners-top dropshadow">
      <h3 class="border-dashed-b">Updated on: <%=Objrs.state%></h3>
      <div>
<%
    While Not Objrs.EOF
        Response.Write Objrs("Subject")
        Objrs.MoveNext
    Wend
  name_of_table = cmd.Parameters("@named").value
  added = cmd.Parameters("@added").value
  set cmd = nothing
  set Objrs = nothing
  conn.close
  set conn = nothing
        Response.Write name_of_table
        Response.Write added    
%>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I've tried changing the position of the output items to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some clunkiness because of the way ADO returns command results to both a recordset and as output paramaters.

They are available after the returned recordset is closed, so this order should work:

```
  set Objrs = nothing

  name_of_table = cmd.Parameters("@named").value
  added = cmd.Parameters("@added").value

  set cmd = nothing
  conn.close
  set conn = nothing

  Response.Write name_of_table
  Response.Write added
```

An alternative is to leave the code as it is add switch to a client side cursor with:

```
  conn.Open strConnect
  conn.CursorLocation = 3 '//aduseclient
  set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
```

(Also check that your use of `adCmdStoredProc` should not be replaced with its numeric value if your not linked to a typelib)